# How to avoid auto binding in functional components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, react-functional-component

I have two functional components in ReactJS, Parent and Child.
I pass a function as a prop to the child from the parent component.

```
    const export function Parent() {
      const name = "parent";
      function print_name() {
        console.log(name);
      }
      return (
        <Child print_name={print_name} />
      )
    };
```

child

```
    const export function Child(props) {
      const name = "child";
      props.print_name(); //logs parent
      return (<p>Child</p>)
    }
```

In the above Component Child, the output on console is "parent" or in other words, the function print_name is bound(binding) to Parent Component.
How can I make the function to not bind to the parent component, so that the print_name in the Child Components output "child".

Also, How does binding actually work in the functional-based components?

I don't want to create a separate function in Child component so that I can reuse my code from the Parent component.

Comment: It's not possible to do. You are passing a function as reference. You can pass the child value as argument.

Comment: @MonzoorTamal then how do I pass the function as a copy(pass by value) to the child component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is executed in its context where it's defined, so it refers to the `name` declared before its definition and log it, in order to make it print the child name you have to pass that name as parameter :

```
const export function Parent() {
  const name = "parent";
  function print_name(_name=name) {//by default takes the parent name
    console.log(_name);
  }
  return (
    <Child print_name={print_name} />
  )
};
```

child :

```
const export function Child(props) {
  const name = "child";
  props.print_name(name); //logs child
 props.print_name(); //without parameter it logs parent
  return (<p>Child</p>)
}
```

In React.js the functions passed as props are use to modify parent state from child components, let's suppose that child component is an input that receives a name from parent to edit edit because in child component you cannot mutate props or parent state directly.

**Another suggestion :**

try to clone the function passed via props in the child component like :

```
const export function Child(props) {
  const name = "child";

Function.prototype.clone = function() {
  return new Function('return ' + this.toString())();
};


const print_child=props.print_name.clone();

   print_child();//expected to log child

  return (<p>Child</p>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Boussadjra, One more thing how do I pass the function as a copy instead of a reference?

Comment: try out `props.print_name.bind({name:name})` in child component

Comment: nice suggestion, but there is no "this" involved in the function, so it will not work. The function print_name is referenced and has a scope of the Parent component, so it accesses the name from Parent component, had it been class based components it may have worked fine.

Comment: And it should be props.print_name.bind({name:name})()

Comment: No @Boussadjra, It doesn't work in functional components, It prints "parent".
I meant to say that It will work in class-based components.

Comment: i want to suggest something but i'm not sure if it will work

Comment: Nice Another suggestion, but React uses a clever way to pass the function as props,
In the Function.prototype.clone function, I console.log(this.toString()), I get this print_name() {
                return _print_name();
            }
So, React is not giving me the access to the function definition, instead it has it's own private declaration prefixed with an underscore. 
Can't access the prefixed function.

Comment: I tried to go to print_name function's scope by using this.prototype.getAccess = function() { console.log(_print_name()) } then this().getAccess() But this gives error that there is no function named _print_name

Comment: So, there is a lot more going internally.

Comment: i need to understand why are you doing that because what you're trying to do is anti-pattern

Comment: Yeah @Boussadjra, I was just trying to see if it is possible.
Now It's clear that it is not possible.
Thanks.